# Get \printindex or \lstlistoflisting to TOC with correct numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, appendices

So when you create an index or a listoflistings, they are not listed in \tableofcontents.

```
\appendix
\newpage
\printindex
\newpage
\lstlistoflistings
```

To make them appear, I entered custom content lines

```
\appendix
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index}
\printindex
```

They now appear, but without numbering;

```
A. Bibliography
Listings
Index
```

How can I make them get the correct numbering? I don't want it to be static, because the order may change or some more appendices are added...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a bibliography and an index are *never* numbered!

Comment: @ApoY2k: TRADITION. Do yourself a favour and page through a number of books. Even beter try to find a copy of a good style manual such as the Chicago Manual of Style.

Comment: it is obviously that they are at the end of each publication, if present. It makes no sense to have it numbered.

Comment: some people say yes and some no, so it is your decision ...

Comment: Okay then. I'll go with including the bibliography at least, as it's an important part of the document (paper for studying)... index and lol maybe not so.

Answer (score 2):

As option to your document class:

```
\documentclass[...,
liststotocnumbered, % All lists are numbered in the TOC
...]{scrarctl}
```